# Add section after 7 cell created in TableView - Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, sections

I have 2 arrays, one that is containing the sections and another one that is containing the elements for populate the cells of my TableView.

The question is: is it possible to create multiple sections with title after 7 cells?

For example, the array contains 14 elements and sections array 2 elements. I wish that at the beginning will appear "Section 1" then first 7 elements, then "Section 2" then the rest of the elements.

Thank you!

```
 import UIKit

    class ChallengesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        var titleArray = [""]
        var weekSection = ["1","2"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


>      let url = URL(string:"https://website.com/file.txt")!
>         URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
>         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
>             if error != nil {
>                 print(error!)
>             }
>             else {
>                 if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
>                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
>                     self.titleArray = textFile.components(separatedBy: "\n")
>                     self.tableView.reloadData()
>                     print(self.titleArray)
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         task.resume()

        }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return titleArray.count
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return weekSection.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "challengeCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeTableViewCell
            cell.labelTitle.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

            switch (section) {
            case 0:
                return "Case 0"
            case 1:
                return "Case 1"
            default:
                return "Default"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Case \(section)"
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let lastSection = titleArray.count % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1
    return (titleArray.count/7) + lastSection
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = titleArray.count - (7*section)
    return min(7,count)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "challengeCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeTableViewCell
    let rowIndex = (indexPath.section*7)+indexPath.row
    cell.labelTitle.text = titleArray[rowIndex]
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" for what about the numberOfSectionsInTableView

Comment: Still, showing only first row and 7 elements. So it's missing section 2 with the other 7 elements

Comment: 14 elements from count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193512/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-pietro-messineo).

Answer (score 0):

after the edit of the question, this is one of the best answers I think

```
extension Array {
 func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
     return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
         Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
     }
 }
}
```

usage:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var titleArray: [[String]] = [[]]
    var sectionsCount: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string:"https://website.com/file.txt")!
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }
            else {
                if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let myArray = textFile.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                        self.sectionsCount = myArray.chunked(into: 7).count
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        print(self.titleArray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionsCount
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArray[section].count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "challengeCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeTableViewCell

        let sectionArray = titleArray[indexPath.section]
        cell.labelTitle.text = sectionArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: But how to organize them in the TableView for show the sections?

Comment: Great! And if I'm managing the array dynamically? In the meaning that I'm updating it through my server?

Comment: explain better please

Comment: Basically my array is empty at the beginning. Then I'm reading an online text file, and filling it with the elements and reloading the TableView.

Comment: at the end of your request or inside your completion block(if you have one) just put a `tableView.reloadData()`; maybe then, cause you are not sure your `titleArray` got 7 or more elements you can check, before splitting, `if titleArray.count > 7` else you will get a fatal error cause index is out of range

Comment: Yes but the fact is, you recommended me to create a second array, but if I will have the case where I will have an array with 21 elements? What should I do?

Comment: I updated the question for let you better understand what I mean.

Comment: ok I just got the question, you want a new section every 7 elements right?

Comment: Yes exactly ! I want a new section with a new title

Comment: Seen but it's adding only 2 elements.

Comment: this function splits your array in blocks of 7, so if you have 14 or less elements you got only 2 sections

Comment: 14 elements inside my array

Comment: sorry you need to put that code in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

Comment: Now it's showing all the 14 elements under first section.

Comment: And for pass the data to the cell? cellForRowAt

Comment: Now it's not retrieving any data from my file online.

Comment: cause `tableView.reloadData()` was before `self.sectionsCount`